# Make Bootstrap 3 non responsive with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

There is a lot of stuff out there on making BS3 non responsive but it all seems to focus on LESS variables. I'm using static CSS though.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/
http://bigwilliam.com/turn-off-responsive-behavior-for-bootstrap-3/

Steps 1 (remove viewport) and 2 (static container width) are easy enough. But how do I set the media query breakpoints in CSS?

Comment: You want it to be non-responsive? Use pixels instead of percentages, use sizes instead of ems. Not sure why you would want to do this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option in Bootstrap to `customize` your download of Bootstrap CSS to fit your needs. If you press the link `customize` along Bootstrap's website, it will take you to a page that lists all the components and utilities that come included with the default download of Bootstrap CSS. You can add/remove any of these items to create a version of bootstrap that fits your particular needs.

For you case, remove the following options (Under Common CSS):

- Print Media Styles
- Responsive Utilities

There is also a section where you can customize and compile the LESS variables into a custom .css file. The one you could consider changing is the **Media Query Breakpoints** settings, but there are lots of customization options for you to browse through.

Take a look here at [Bootstrap/Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to see all the options you can change, and hopefully that will help!

Answer (score 0):

set minimal width to html or body element, in that way page won't resize if browser width is less than min-width specified. but whole point using bootstrap is to easily develop responsive websites, so you are doing something terribly wrong if you want not responsive bootstrap.

```
html { min-width: 1000px; }
```